# Icecast2 - how to add access-control-allow-origin header?

Tags: http-headers, xmlhttprequest, debian, icecast

Im trying to stream music from my icecast2 server using [Dancer.js](https://github.com/jsantell/dancer.js/) which is using XHR.

However, currently I'm getting the error (replaced the actual domain with example.com):

`XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://example.com:8000/stream.ogg. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://example.com' is therefore not allowed access.`

I have been searching around for information on how to add custom headers to the stream, but couldn't find any information about this.

How can I add the access-control-allow-origin header to this stream?

I saw some anwsers telling me to add it in the apache config or .htaccess but since this isn't using the apache service that wouldn't work.

Thanks.

Comment: I think there is a way to add headers in Icecast, but I don't remember off the top of my head.  If you don't get this working, CORS headers are standard in my own server, AudioPump.  If you want to try it out, e-mail me at brad@audiopump.co

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proper™ way to do this is to upgrade to Icecast 2.4.1 which has this feature explicitly added to aid the use of it's (fixed) JSON API and HTML5 features.

Packages are available for most distributions. See http://icecast.org

Comment: good to know they added it, there was absolutely no easy way of doing this back when I asked the question

Comment: Yes, just wanted to add this, so that if someone stumbles across this question they have a chance to take the easy route. ;-)

Comment: I just searched for this again and ended up on my own question again xD glad you added that info haha

Answer (score 0):

You can add the the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header to client response of Icecast trunk
by add your header  the following line in the util_http_build_header function of [util.c](http://svn.xiph.org/icecast/trunk/icecast/src/util.c).

See the `"Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://foo.example\r\n",` after  contenttype_buffer.

```
ret = snprintf (out, len, "%sServer: %s\r\n%s%s%s%s%s%s",
                              status_buffer,
                  config->server_id,
                  currenttime_buffer,
                  contenttype_buffer,
                  "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://foo.example\r\n",
                  (status == 401 ? "WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm=\"Icecast2 Server\"\r\n" : ""),
                              (cache     ? "" : "Cache-Control: no-cache\r\n"
                                                "Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT\r\n"
                                                "Pragma: no-cache\r\n"),
                              (datablock ? "\r\n" : ""),
                              (datablock ? datablock : ""));
```

You can add the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header to the client response of Icecast 2.3.2 by adding the following

```
bytes = snprintf (ptr, remaining, "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://foo.example\r\n");
remaining -= bytes;
ptr += bytes;
```

to the format_prepare_headers method in [format.c](http://sourcecodebrowser.com/icecast2/2.3.2/format_8c.html#ad3384e552d825fad8d437b62d80c853f) after the line that adds the Server header and before the line that adds the Cache Control header.

Other improvements to this suggestion include making the header name and values Icecast configuration variables (adding them to the ice_config_tag struct in [cfgfile.h](http://sourcecodebrowser.com/icecast2/2.3.2/cfgfile_8h_source.html) and accessing them before you call `config_release_config();`) or adding handling to support generic (e.g. no ICY) headers from the source , as the current logic in the same function adds icy to all headers from the source.

If you added the variable for custom header to [cfgfile.h,](http://svn.xiph.org/icecast/trunk/icecast/src/cfgfile.h) for example
`char *custom_header;` add to the struct definition, and then modify `_parse_root`, `config_clear`,`_set_defaults` functions in [cfgfile.c](http://svn.xiph.org/icecast/trunk/icecast/src/cfgfile.c), you will able to set the custom header in the Icecast configuration file, like any other configuration variable.

Comment: where would I be able to configure the header if I added it in cfgfile.h? I have no experience developing in C so this is all a bit new to me. also the server and cache-control header lines have been removed in the current (2.4.0) version